# How to put round brackets in Latex pseudocode

Tags: syntax, latex

I have the following pseudocode in latex

```
\begin{algorithm}
\begin{algorithmic}
.....
\State i = (i + 1) \% CAPACITY
.....
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
```

However, when I compile this, the round bracket do not show up and instead of getting `i = (i + 1) % QCAPACITY`, I get `i = i + 1 % QCAPACITY`. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: this should be migrated to http://tex.stackexchange.com

Comment: Have you tried `\left(i + 1\right) \% CAPACITY`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure your code is right? I've pasted this code into [ScribTeX](http://www.scribtex.com) and I got it right.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
\begin{algorithmic}

\State i = (i + 1) \% CAPACITY

\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}​
```